# fetch bandcamp user discography json in wordpress

Tags: php, json, wordpress, api

I am writing a WordPress plugin to fetch all personal releases (discography) from Bandcamp and display on a WordPress site.

For reference: http://bandcamp.com/developer

I have managed to get the first call for the discography and store it in the database and use any info from the json file around the site.

```
/*
 *  assign global variables
 *
*/
$plugin_url = WP_PLUGIN_URL . '/bandcamp-integration';
$options = array();

/*
 *  create admin menu link under 'Settings > Bandcamp'
 *
*/

function bodhi_bi_admin_menu() {

    add_options_page(
        'Bandcamp Integration',
        'Bandcamp',
        'manage_options',
        'bi-options',
        'bodhi_bi_options_page'
    );

}
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'bodhi_bi_admin_menu' );

/*
 *  create admin options page under 'Settings > Bandcamp'
 *
*/

function bodhi_bi_options_page() {

    if( ! current_user_can( 'manage_options' ) ) {

        wp_die( 'Nice try, you cannot access this page.' );

    }

    global $plugin_url;
    global $options;

    if( isset( $_POST['bodhi_bi_band_id_form_submitted'] ) ) {

        $hidden_field = esc_html( $_POST['bodhi_bi_band_id_form_submitted'] );

        if( $hidden_field == 'Y' ) {

            $bodhi_bi_band_id = esc_html( $_POST['bodhi_bi_band_id'] );
            $bodhi_bi_bc_discog = bodhi_bi_get_bandcamp_discog( $bodhi_bi_band_id );

            $options['bodhi_bi_band_id']    = $bodhi_bi_band_id;
            $options['bodhi_bi_bc_discog']  = $bodhi_bi_bc_discog;
            $options['last_updated']        = time();

            update_option( 'bodhi_bi_discog', $options );

        }

    }

    $options = get_option( 'bodhi_bi_discog' );

    if( $options != '' ) {

        $bodhi_bi_band_id = $options['bodhi_bi_band_id'];
        $bodhi_bi_bc_discog = $options['bodhi_bi_bc_discog'];

    }

    // options page markup
    require( 'includes/options-page-wrapper.php' );

}

/*
 *  get bandcamp discography
 *
*/

function bodhi_bi_get_bandcamp_discog( $bodhi_bi_band_id ) {

    // WHY YOU NOT WORK???
    //$json_feed_discog_url = 'http://api.bandcamp.com/api/band/3/discography?key=' . $bc_dev_key . '&band_id=' . $bodhi_bi_band_id;

    // WORKS
    $json_feed_discog_url = 'http://api.bandcamp.com/api/band/3/discography?key=ACTUALBANDCAMPKEYHERE&band_id=' . $bodhi_bi_band_id;

    $args = array( 'timeout' => 120 );

    $json_feed_discog = wp_remote_get( $json_feed_discog_url, $args );

    $bodhi_bi_bc_discog = json_decode( $json_feed_discog['body'] );

    return $bodhi_bi_bc_discog;

}
```

This stores the discography json feed in the database so i can call info from it like so:

```
// count total number of releases in discography
$total_releases = count( $bodhi_bi_bc_discog->discography );
echo 'Number of releases: ' . $total_releases;
```

OR

```
// list layout (inline styles just for testing)
foreach( $bodhi_bi_bc_discog->discography as $result ) {
    echo '<li style="width:100%;list-style:none;border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;padding-bottom:2.2em;overflow:hidden;">';
    echo '<h2 style="font-weight:normal;">' . $result->title . '</h2>';
    echo '<img style="float:left;margin-right:1em;" src="' . $result->large_art_url . '" alt="' . $result->title . '" />';
    echo $result->artist;
    echo '<br />';
    echo $result->title;
    echo '<br />';
    echo '<a href="' .$result->url . '?action=buy">BUY</a>';
    echo '<br />';
    echo '<a href="' .$result->url . '?action=download">DOWNLOAD</a>';
    echo '</li>';
}
```

My issue is that Bandcamp makes you pull each album's info separately from the discography and then each track's info separately again (in order to get streaming url's and specific info about each track).

I managed to pull all of the album_id's and track_id's out into arrays and then foreach - add them to the correct url for retrieving the json, but this is just in a page template at the moment and I would like it all in the functions.

```
$album_ids = array();
$track_ids = array();

for( $i=0; $i<=count( $bodhi_bi_bc_discog->discography ); $i++ ) {

    if ( $bodhi_bi_bc_discog->{'discography'}[$i]->{'album_id'} != '' ) {

        $album_ids[$i] = $bodhi_bi_bc_discog->{'discography'}[$i]->{'album_id'};

    }

    if ( $bodhi_bi_bc_discog->{'discography'}[$i]->{'track_id'} != '' ) {

        $track_ids[$i] = $bodhi_bi_bc_discog->{'discography'}[$i]->{'track_id'};

    }

    // echo '<br />loop works';
}

foreach( $album_ids as $album_id ) {
    $feed_url = 'http://api.bandcamp.com/api/album/2/info?key=' . $bc_dev_key . '&album_id=' . $album_id;
    echo '<br />' . $feed_url;
}
foreach( $track_ids as $track_id ) {
    $feed_url = 'http://api.bandcamp.com/api/track/3/info?key=' . $bc_dev_key . '&track_id=' . $track_id;
    echo '<br />' . $feed_url;
}
```

So, I would really appreciate some help getting all of these feeds and storing in the database like I have for the main discography one.
I also then need to do a similar thing to get the tracks of each album.

Ultimately, I just need access to every bit of information, a complete discography from the database and not have to call the bandcamp api so many damn times and especially not on page load.

I hope this makes sense! Thanks for any help in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out - I had to create 2 more functions similar to the first that gets the discography.
I added the results to the original option update so it is all in the same db entry.
all good :)